# Any function in Gnuplot that is equivalent of the Beeswarm dotplot?

Tags: gnuplot

I am looking for a function in Gnuplot to create a so called Beeswarm dotplot. This is very popular plots used in medicine and biology. I know it can be done in Grapgpad Prism and in R but I would like to continue using Gnuplots for making graphs

Comment: There has been a request on a gnuplot mailinglist, and a first patch for such a functionality is available at http://sourceforge.net/p/gnuplot/patches/722/ Otherwise you must use an external tool to do some preprocessing on your data.

Comment: Now that functionality is available in gnuplot's development version, see http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/demo_5.1/jitter.html for some demos.

Comment: Thanks for all the help,